# "smartContract.at is not a function" in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, ethereum, web3js

In my Angular Dapp , in the first code the error is "smartContract.at is not a function".

```
  settingMap(hashRoot : string) {
 var smartContract = new window.web3.eth.Contract([contractAbi])
 var contract = smartContract.at(contractAddress)
 var owner = smartContract.owner
 console.log(owner)
```

But if i write the code in this way:

```
 settingMap(hashRoot : string) {
var smartContract = new window.web3.eth.Contract([contractAbi],contractAddress)
var owner = smartContract.owner
console.log(owner)
```

the console.log print undefined.
How can i resolve this problem? I have tried in many ways, even changing the line of code

```
"var smartContract = window.web3.eth.contract([contractAbi])"
```

in

```
 "var smartContract = new window.web3.eth.Contract([contractAbi])"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `web3` version `1.x.x`, then the mechanism for contract instance is changed as shown below:

```
var smartContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
```

And you can call the public methods/variables if they does not require to be mined as shown below:

```
await smartContract.methods.owner().call();
```